# Outlook amend task form

Tags: microsoft-outlook, forms, microsoft-outlook-2016

I am completely new to working with Outlook forms, so please phrase your answers accordingly! I've been asked to amend the built in Task form do do away with status, replacing it with a new combo box and add two new text fields.

I've been reading round the web for a couple of hours and I get the feeling you can't make amendments to the the built in Task form. Is this correct?

Comment: This really isn't something we can teach on this site. There are lots of great resources out there to walk you through this. Once you have a form in place or are developing it, we can try to help with specific questions related to it. Here is a good instructional page to get started - [Designing Custom Outlook Forms](http://www.slipstick.com/developer/designing-custom-forms/). Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, and I appreciate it's a bit vague, the question I really looking to answer is - is it not possible to amend the built in Task form? I'll amend my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"You cannot customize the default pages of a task form by using Microsoft Outlook form pages. However, you can hide these pages and create new pages on the form."

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868611.aspx